# AcroForm comb TextField in Itextpdf7

Tags: java, itext

Sorry for my English....
Using sluduyuschy code, I want to add a field in a PDF document that it had been a combination of several characters, and were filled, but it becomes a combination of just after I click on it from Adober reader or fill in it from the Adobe Reader again.
That see as [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQHm6.png), only when i click that see good [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGF7d.png)
What am I doing wrong

```
public class TestClass {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    PdfWriter writer  = new PdfWriter("D:\\TestPdf.pdf");
    PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);
    PdfAcroForm myAcro = PdfAcroForm.getAcroForm(pdf,true);
    pdf.addNewPage();
    PdfFormField text = PdfFormField.createText(pdf,new Rectangle(0f,800f,200f,50f),"textValue","")
            .setFileSelect(false)  //Meaningful only if the MaxLen entry is present in the text field dictionary and if the Multiline, Password, and FileSelect flags are clear. If true, the field is automatically divided into as many equally spaced positions, or combs, as the value of MaxLen, and the text is laid out into those combs.
            .setMultiline(false)   
            .setPassword(false)    
            .setMaxLen(5)
            .setComb(true);


    text.setValue("What not good!");
    text.regenerateField();
    myAcro.addField(text);
    pdf.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to set `myAcro.setNeedAppearances(true);`

Comment: it worked . Thank you very much. How long have I suffered, now I realize how little my knowledge.